# How to distinguish smartcard reader from fingerprint reader using winapi (winscard.h)

Tags: c, winapi, smartcard, fingerprint, reader

In order to retrieve readers on my computer, I should use:

```
SCARDCONTEXT SCardContext;
if (SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE_USER, NULL, NULL, &SCardContext)) {
  char ReaderNames[1000];
  DWORD Length = 1000;
  if(Status = SCardListReaders(SCardContext, NULL, ReaderNames, &Length)) {
    SCARD_READERSTATE ReaderStates[PCSC_READER_MAX_COUNT];
    DWORD ReaderCount = 0;
    // Place the readers into the state array.
    LPSTR Rdr = ReaderNames;
    for (DWORD dwI = 0; dwI < MAXIMUM_SMARTCARD_READERS; dwI++ )
    {
      if (0 == *Rdr)
        break;
      ReaderStates[dwI].szReader = Rdr;
      ReaderStates[dwI].dwCurrentState = SCARD_STATE_UNAWARE;
      Rdr += lstrlen(szRdr) + 1;
    }
    ReaderCount = dwI;

    // Do something with the readers;
  }
  SCardReleaseContext(SCardContext);
}
```

How would I identify which reader is actually a card reader, and which one is a fingerprint reader, or face recognition?

I use Windows Hello Fingerprint reader, and it is shown as a smartcard reader in the above code. I tried to get the status of each reader with [`SCardGetStatusChangeA()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard/nf-winscard-scardgetstatuschangea). The fingerprint reader returns `0x422`, which means `SCARD_STATE_UNPOWERED | SCARD_STATE_PRESENT | SCARD_STATE_CHANGED`.

How can a fingerprint reader return `SCARD_STATE_PRESENT`?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct interface? Having a biometric device being directly driven by PCSC (read: PC to SC, where SC = Smart Card) / ISO 7816-4 seems .... weird. I guess that using a [higher level API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbiomet/biometric-framework-overview) makes more sense?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I would like to use SC reader. I think [winscard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winscard) is the right API. I just can not distinguish it from fingerprint reader.

Comment: Isn't a fingerprint the *equivalent* of "card present"? Certainly the finger is present.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbio/nf-winbio-winbioverify

Comment: @WeatherVane Status is returned without fingerprint reader being touched.

Comment: And does the card reader return status without reading a card?

Comment: @WeatherVane Of course. This is status of a reader, not actually reading a card. Status is returned for example if card is inserted to the reader: SCARD_STATE_PRESENT, or card is removed: SCARD_STATE_EMPTY

Comment: Does [QueryCards](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/7cbd99ac1d2b4a0beffbaba29ea63d024ceff700/Samples/Win7Samples/security/smartcard/smartcardapi/scquery/SCQuery.Cpp#L429) function work for you? Try to connect readers to get more information.

Comment: And @Nikola, why do you want to distinguish fingerprint readers from smartcard readers while *winscard* has abstracted them? It could be not the right API to distinguish.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT which API would you recommend for the task?